# How to stop redirecting to front page url in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How to stop redirecting to the front page URL when using a sub-domain in WordPress? 
Actually my issue when Im going to `https://subdomain.domain.com` it always redirect to `https://subdomain.domain.com/en/frontpage/` .

I can go to any other pages such as `https://subdomain.domain.com/shop/`, but only front page with sub-domain redirect to `https://subdomain.domain.com/en/frontpage/`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think this is the same question and you will find your answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71927/how-to-prevent-automatic-redirection

Comment: ok thankyou, let me check

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your theme or some plugin is using Url rewrite functionality and if Uri is /, they redirecting you to /en/frontpage